# Delete all the whitespaces that occur after a word in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string "  hello world! How is it going?"

The output I need is "  helloworld!Howisitgoing?"

So all the whitespaces after hello should be removed. I am trying to do this in ruby using regex.

I tried strip and delete(' ') methods but I didn't get what I wanted.

```
some_string = "  hello world! How is it going?"
some_string.delete(' ') #deletes all spaces
some_string.strip #removes trailing and leading spaces only
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: Maybe chain them together.

Comment: If you're just practicing regex, then \s matches a whitespace, a tab, an LF or a CRLF. You can **replace** such characters with an empty string `''`. See the documentation of `String#gsub` and `String#gsub!`

Comment: You aren't assigning the new value back into the variable. Try `some_string = some_string.delete(' ')` etc. Or like @SagarPandya said above, you can string them all on the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways this could be accomplished without without a regular expressions, but using them could be the "cleanest" looking approach without taking sub-strings, etc. The regular expression I believe you are looking for is `/(?!^)(\s)/`.

```
"  hello world! How is it going?".gsub(/(?!^)(\s)/, '')
#=> " helloworld!Howisitgoing?"
```

The `\s` matched any whitespace character (including tabs, etc), and the `^` is an "anchor" meaning the beginning of the string. The `!` indicates to reject a match with following criteria. Using those together to your goal can be accomplished.

If you are not familiar with [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), it is very similar to `replace`, but takes a regular expression. It additionally has a `gsub!` counter-part to mutate the string in place without creating a new altered copy.

Note that strictly speaking, this isn't all whitespace "after a word" to quote the exact question, but I gathered from your examples that your intentions were "all whitespace except beginning of string", which this will do.

Comment: Why is `\s` in a capture group?

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_spaces_after_word(str, word)
  i = str.index(/\b#{word}\b/i)
  return str if i.nil?
  i += word.size
  str.gsub(/ /) { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) >= i ? '' : ' ' }
end

remove_spaces_after_word("Hey hello world! How is it going?", "hello")
  #=> "Hey helloworld!Howisitgoing?"
```